# facebook iphone - how login under different user

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a game for iphone, so my question:
How is the end user supposed to change his login. Meaning if he decides to log in under a different name?

I noticed that even a resetting of the phone and reinstalling the app doesn't work, I'm still logged in under the same user as before.
My next guess was FB.Logout, but this page tells me not to use it:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Logout

And also, under Settings -> Facebook I logged into another user already, too - in my game it's still using the old user...

Answer (score 3):

You need to set

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

for Facebook Logout.

closeAndClearTokenInformation closes the session and clears any cached info, destroying the session. This means that when the app is re-launched the cached token will not be available. The login view will then be shown.

Answer (score 1):

That is because that LogOut function will log out the user from FACEBOOK, not just from your app. Plus the documentation you are looking at is for unity. You should follow this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

They show how you can easily log in and log out which is what you are looking for. If you don't have a predefined account set on the device then you will be able to log in with your email and password using the facebook log in interface (in were you can log in as a different user if you want)

Comment: What do you mean by 'predefined account set on the device'? It seems like on some phones I can log in and out, but on my current iPhone I simply cannot log out anymore. Even if I reinstall the app, he's still automatically logged in.

Comment: Your phone has a system wide facebook account. This is shown in the settings. As long as this account is set in the settings you wont be able to log in as a different user on THAT device, because the iphone sdk calls automatically the default device user. The phones in were you can change the user do not have this Facebook account set. Altho if you want to try to find a workaround for this (not sure if it is possible) you should make another question for it so that people can help you.

Comment: ok - that sounds good - thanks! I was able to log in under another user name now. I think I was hitting a bug before where, in Settings I was logged in under a different user name than in the game. But somehow that's gone away